# ASP.NET MVC : Change input text value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap modal that shows the images of Gallery, when you click on it. I want change input value by clicking on each  image and put their **Url** on **input text** for **submit** . But it doesn't work and value of input text doesn't change . Why?

```
    @model IEnumerable<tourism.Models.Gallery>

    <input type="text" name="imgUrl" id="index-img" style="width: 100%;" value="url" />

 <div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Choose Image</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Gallery</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row">

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#" onclick="(function () {    ('input[name=imgUrl]').val()=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url); })()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alt)"></a>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery code for passing Url from model to input text(from above code) :

```
<a href="#" onclick="(function () {    ('input[name=imgUrl]').val()=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url); })()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alt)"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the link to add a `data-` value for the items url (remove your `onclick=...`)

```
<a href="#" data-url="@item.Url" class="image" .... >
```

and then add the script to handle the click event of the link to update the input

```
$('.image').click(function() {
  $('#index-img').val($(this).data('url'));
});
```

Comment: Well done . Thank you sir . do you have some good source for learning jquery?

Comment: sorry , but what is role of 'data-url' here?

Comment: I would first start with understanding [Unobtrusive_JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). The best site IMO is the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Html `data-` attributes are a way of adding arbitrary data to html elements (refer the jquery documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/data/)). In this case, its storing the value of your objects `Url` property to a `data` property named `url` which you can then retrieve using `.data('url')`. You can store pretty much anything you want

Comment: Another [source worth reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)